# PyArg_ParseTuple SegFaults in CApi

Tags: python, numpy, python-c-api

I am writing a code, trying to get used to the C API of NumPy arrays.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


static char doc[] =
"Document";

static PyArrayObject *
    trace(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){

    PyArrayObject *matin;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!",&PyArray_Type, &matin))
         return NULL;

    printf("a");
    return matin;
}

static PyMethodDef TraceMethods[] = {
    {"trace", trace, METH_VARARGS, doc},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
inittrace(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("trace", TraceMethods);
    import_array();
}
```

This is a stripped-down version. I just want to be able to get an object of type `PyArrayObject` and return it back. Unfortunately this gives a SegFault also.

Linux, 64-bit, Python 2.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html):

> `O` (object) [PyObject *]
> Store a Python object (without any conversion) in a C object pointer. The C program thus receives the actual object that was passed. **The object’s reference count is not increased.** The pointer stored is not *NULL*.
>
> `O!` (object) [*typeobject*, PyObject *]
> Store a Python object in a C object pointer. This is similar to `O`, but...

You're returning a stolen reference. Increment it first.

Comment: I'm not familiar with software architecture with C, but I guess  when I don't increment the reference with `PYINCREF(the_python_object);` then the garbage collector spots that its reference is 0, and frees that memory. (correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Essentially yes, but it's the refcount dropping to 0 that invokes the GC rather than the other way around.