# Python object extension which gets a list in constructor never passes the creation step (SIGSEV), why?

Tags: python, numpy, segmentation-fault, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I've been fighting for a lot of time with an error and I've run short of ideas on what's happening and why it doesn't work.

First of all, I'm trying to create a new object type for Python through a C extension. This object is created using a list, numpy array etc... But I cannot even make this part work.

The actual minimal code that fails is:

```
    #include <python2.7/Python.h>
    #include <python2.7/structmember.h>
    #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
    #include "../python/NumpyHelperFuncs.h"
    #include <cmath>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    typedef struct {
        PyObject_HEAD
    } CondensedMatrix;

    static void condensedMatrix_dealloc(CondensedMatrix* self){
        self->ob_type->tp_free((PyObject*)self);
    }

    static PyObject* condensedMatrix_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds){
        CondensedMatrix *self;
        self = (CondensedMatrix*) type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
        return (PyObject *) self;
    }

    static int condensedMatrix_init(CondensedMatrix *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds){
        PyObject* input;
        PyArrayObject* rmsd_numpy_array;
        cout<<"Minimum class creation"<<flush<<endl;

        if (! PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O",&input)){
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Error parsing parameters.");
            return -1;
        }
        rmsd_numpy_array = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_ContiguousFromObject(input, PyArray_FLOAT, 1, 1);
        Py_DECREF(rmsd_numpy_array);
        return 0;
    }

    static PyMemberDef condensedMatrix_members[] = {
        {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
    };


    static PyMethodDef condensedMatrix_methods[] = {
        {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
    };

    static PyTypeObject CondensedMatrixType = {
        PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
        0,                                              /*ob_size*/
        "condensedMatrix.CondensedMatrixType",          /*tp_name*/
        sizeof(CondensedMatrix),    /*tp_basicsize*/
        0,                         /*tp_itemsize*/
        (destructor)condensedMatrix_dealloc, /*tp_dealloc*/
        0,                         /*tp_print*/
        0,                         /*tp_getattr*/
        0,                         /*tp_setattr*/
        0,                         /*tp_compare*/
        0,                         /*tp_repr*/
        0,                         /*tp_as_number*/
        0,                         /*tp_as_sequence*/
        0,                         /*tp_as_mapping*/
        0,                         /*tp_hash */
        0,                         /*tp_call*/
        0,                         /*tp_str*/
        0,                         /*tp_getattro*/
        0,                         /*tp_setattro*/
        0,                         /*tp_as_buffer*/
        Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT| Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE ,                       /*tp_flags*/
        "Condensed matrix as in pdist",         /* tp_doc */
        0,                     /* tp_traverse */
        0,                     /* tp_clear */
        0,                     /* tp_richcompare */
        0,                     /* tp_weaklistoffset */
        0,                         /* tp_iter */
        0,                         /* tp_iternext */
        condensedMatrix_methods,   /* tp_methods */
        condensedMatrix_members,   /* tp_members */
        0,                         /* tp_getset */
        0,                         /* tp_base */
        0,                         /* tp_dict */
        0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
        0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
        0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
        (initproc)condensedMatrix_init, /* tp_init */
        0,                              /* tp_alloc */
        condensedMatrix_new,                /* tp_new */
    };

    #ifndef PyMODINIT_FUNC  /* declarations for DLL import/export */
    #define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
    #endif

    PyMODINIT_FUNC initcondensedMatrix(void){
        PyObject* module;

        if (PyType_Ready(&CondensedMatrixType) < 0)
            return;

        module = Py_InitModule3("condensedMatrix", NULL,"Fast Access Condensed Matrix");
        if (module == NULL)
              return;

        Py_INCREF(&CondensedMatrixType);
        PyModule_AddObject(module, "CondensedMatrix", (PyObject*) &CondensedMatrixType);
    }
```

This code has been written following the tips (and copy/pasting): [http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#id2)

I've tested the Noddy code and it works, but if I add a fourth parameter to get a list, it also exits with a sigsev.

I compile the code above with:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  -fPIC  -c matrix.cpp

g++ -pthread -shared matrix/matrix.o -lpython2.7 -o condensedMatrix.so -fopenmp
```

And I use it with:
    if **name** == '**main**':
        data_con = [3,4,5,6]
        matrix = CondensedMatrix(data_con)

I've also read [PyArg_ParseTuple SegFaults in CApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760658/pyarg-parsetuple-segfaults-in-capi)

Does anyone know why it does a segfault after pyarg_parsetuple?

Ubuntu 12.04 , gcc 4.6.3 , Python 2.7.3

Thanks!

Comment: Attach a debugger to it and step through it?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like the error was indeed very easy to solve as the only needed thing was a missing 'import_array();' sentence in the init function:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC initcondensedMatrix(void){
    PyObject* module;

    if (PyType_Ready(&CondensedMatrixType) < 0)
        return;

    module = Py_InitModule3("condensedMatrix", NULL,"Fast Access Condensed Matrix");
    if (module == NULL)
          return;

    Py_INCREF(&CondensedMatrixType);
    PyModule_AddObject(module, "CondensedMatrix", (PyObject*) &CondensedMatrixType);
    import_array();
}
```

And that was all ...